# I want to only page number in citation and want to remove extra title field appeared in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

My tex file content is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla-new]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{workcited.bib}
@inbook{chatterji,
author = "Partha Chatterji",
title = "The nation and its fragments",
date = "1994",
pages = "8-9",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{workscited}

\begin{document}
Partha Chatterjee discusses this point in his lecture Our Modernity in detail.
He says that the forms of modernity differ between different countries depending upon the milieu and social practices of each.
He says “…true modernity consists in determining the particular forms of modernity that are suitable in particular circumstances; that is, applying the methods of reason to identify and invent the specific technologies of modernity that are appropriate to our purpose. \autocite[8-9]{chatterji}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Output

I am getting as an output

[image: I want to remove the auther's name]

and work cited as

[image: i want to remove the extra title appeared]

I would like to get the output as

> Partha Chatterjee says “…true modernity consists in determining the
>   particular forms of modernity that are suitable in particular
>   circumstances; that is, applying the methods of reason to identify and
>   invent the specific technologies of modernity that are appropriate to
>   our purpose.” (8-9).

I want *only page numbers* in output as (8-9) , not the author's name along with page numbers as required in MLA 8 .
In work cited page i got an extra title which I want to remove too.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077)! Please rephrased your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Comment: OK, I rewrote the code to a MWE. But please edit the beginning of your question by explaining the goal / problem.

Comment: The names of the bib files from the `filecontents` environment and `\bibliography` don't match.

Comment: For your page number problem: how about using `(8-9)\nocite{chatterji}`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your entry `chatterji` is a `@book` and not an `@inbook`. `@inbook`s refer only to a selected section (usually a chapter) of a `@book`. An `@inbook` needs a `title` and a `booktitle` field. But *The nation and its fragments* is the entire book and so I suggest you go with `@book`.

When you write `\autocite[8-9]{chatterji}` `biblatex` prints

> Chatterji 8-9

because that is the full citation for that work. If you have mentioned the author name before and want to suppress it in the citation, you need to use the starred version `\autocite*`. The name will also be suppressed automatically if the last citation was to the same work (using the "ibid." tracker).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla-new]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{chatterji,
  author    = {Partha Chatterji},
  title     = {The Nation and Its Fragments},
  subtitle  = {Colonial and Postcolonial Histories},
  date      = {1993},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  location  = {Princeton},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Partha Chatterjee discusses this point in his lecture Our Modernity in detail.
He says that the forms of modernity differ between different countries depending upon the milieu and social practices of each.
He says \enquote{…true modernity consists in determining the particular forms of modernity that are suitable in particular circumstances; that is, applying the methods of reason to identify and invent the specific technologies of modernity that are appropriate to our purpose} \autocite*[8-9]{chatterji}. 

Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}.

\autocite[8-9]{chatterji}

Lorem \autocite[382]{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite[8-9]{chatterji} dolor \autocite[383]{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Partha Chatterjee discusses this point in his lecture Our Modernity in detail. He says that the forms of modernity differ between different countries depending upon the milieu and social practices of each. He says “...true modernity consists in determining the particular forms of modernity that are suitable in particular circumstances; that is, applying the methods of reason to identify and invent the specific technologies of modernity that are appropriate to our purpose” (8-9).//Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 380) ipsum (381).//(Chatterji 8-9)//Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 382) ipsum (Chatterji 8-9) dolor (Sigfridsson and Ryde 383).//Works Cited//Chatterji, Partha. The Nation and Its Fragments: Colonial and Postcolonial Histories. Princeton University Press, 1993.//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. Journal of Computational Chemistry, vol. 19, no. 4, 1998, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4h377::AID-JCC1i3.0.CO;2-P.]